# Signaling completion of a task from Java to command line

Tags: java, signals, autohotkey, py4j

I'm working on a project that uses Java but has a Python wrapper implemented using Py4J. To make it work properly, I need to first run a Java server (call it `Main.java`) with the correct command line argument, and once the server initializes, I need to run my own Python script on it (call it `Script.py`).

The `Main.java` is where I'd like to signal initialization completion:

```
public class Main {

    ...

    public void initialize() {
        // Server initialization code
        signalInitializationDone();
    }
}
```

Currently I'm simply using the following AHK script `Run.ahk`:

```
Run, javaw Main --py4j
Sleep, 2000
Run, python .\python\Script.py
```

But this of course only works if the initialization finishes in 2 seconds and it also idles unnecessarily if the initialization finishes faster. I'd like to instead have a solution that runs `Script.py` as soon as `Main.initialize()` is done.

One thing I cannot do is:

```
public void initialize() {
    // Server initialization code
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python .\python\Script.py");
}
```

or similar direct calls to the python script from inside the Java application, because the same server may also be run with other scripts or even as a standalone.

I'm also not dead-set on using AHK, any working solution (AHK, Batch, Python, Java) is fine.

Comment: You could parametrize your Java application's initialization with a string representing the script to run or none and still invoke it from java. Then you wrap it up in your py4j script by injecting the parameter.

Comment: Did you try RunWait?  Alternatively, you might capture your OutputVarPID and query processes (every quarter second or so) to see when it shows up.  Lastly, can the server initialization throw a dialog? Then AHK can look for WinActive, etc.

Comment: Adding extra parameters might be tricky - the Java application is actually not mine and I'd like to edit it as little as possible.

The problem with RunWait is that the server process keeps running after initializing and querying for process name or PID is problematic because the java process appears before initialization. The dialog idea might work, I'll try it if I can't figure out a better way.